# how to edit x-banner component - laravel jetstream

Tags: php, laravel, components, laravel-jetstream

I am currently trying to edit the jetstream logo displayed within the banner of the default jetstream `localhost:127.0.0.1/dashboard` page. I believe that the actual code for the inside of the banner is within the component `<x-banner>` but I am unable to find this file.

I've researched online as well and I have found all sources to state that you have to run "`php artisan vendor:publish --tag=jetstream-views`" in your terminal to publish the Jetstream views. Then, edit the banner.blade.php file. But every time I run

```
PS C...> php artisan vendor:publish --tag=jetstream-views
```

in my terminal, I get an error message that says:

```
INFO  No publishable resources for tag [jetstream-views].
```

and I can't seem to find an alternative. Is there any way to publish the `jetstream-views`, or to edit the banner without having to do so?